# Under what conditions for $p$ and $q$ will the following equation of a graph touch the x-axis?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=x^3+px+q$

So in order for the graph to touch the x-axis the derivative has to be 0. $y'=3x^2+p$ from here $x=\sqrt \frac{-p}{3}$. but from here I don't know how to go forward I guess I have to solve  the equation $y=x^3+px+q$ for x and then equal it to $x=\sqrt \frac{-p}{3}$, but I don't know how to solve the equation for x. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

The answer is $(\frac{p}{3})^3 + (\frac{q}{2})^2=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the graph to touch the $x$-axis, the derivative must be zero at one of the roots of the cubic equation. Since the values at which the derivative is zero is $\pm\sqrt{-\frac p3}$. Our condition becomes
\begin{align}
&x(x^2+p)+q=0\\
\implies &x(3x^2+p)-2x^3=-q\\
\implies &4x^6=q^2\\
\implies &\frac{(3x^2)^3}{27}=\frac{q^2}{4}\\
\implies &\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}=0
\end{align}
This is the required condition. (Note that when the graph crosses $x$-axis but still the $x$-axis is tangent to the graph at point of intersection, that is also counted as "touched" here. For example, $p=q=0$ satisfies this condition).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for the graph to touch the x-axis, the y-value has to be zero when you plug in the x value you calculated.

Your logic is not quite correct: in fact $y’=0$ when $x= \pm\sqrt{-p/3}$.

Comment: I do that but I still don't get the answer. Is the answer maybe wrong or have I miscalculated something ?

Comment: It’s just algebra to get from the original condition to the textbook answer. You can probably do that algebra better than I can. You do have to worry about the fact that $y’=0$ when $x= -\sqrt{-p/3}$.

Comment: oh, ok. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You want $$f(\sqrt \frac{-p}{3})=0$$

Thus plug $x=\sqrt \frac{-p}{3}$ in your cubic and find the condition for p and q.